# using first 2 letters of a first name and 4 letters of a last to create a username with a random number for example, Michael + Jackson= JackMi42

Tags: java

Good evening programmers, I am new to java and I am stuck on a coding question that is about using first 2 letters of a first name and 4 letters of a last to create a username with a random number for example, Michael + Jackson= JackMi42. If anyone can help me out I will really appreciate it. the application that I am using to do this is Eclipse IDE. Here is the code that I have created so far:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class FirstNameLastName {
/**In this step you put in a last name
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");
        in.nextLine();
        /**In this step you put in any first name
         */
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
        in.nextLine();
        /**In this step you type in the four letters of the last name
         */
        System.out.println("four letters of last name:");
        String FourLetterOfLastName = in.nextLine();
        /**In this step you type in the two letters of the first name
         */
        System.out.println("two letters of first name:");
        String TwoLetterOfFirstName = in.nextLine();
        /**In this step you type in any number between 10 and 99
         */
        System.out.println("random number between 10 and 99");
        String randomnum = in.nextLine();
        /**In this step you print out the four letter of last name +two letter of first name + a 
         * random number between 10 and 99. 
         * at then end it will print it out on the output section in the console section
         */
        System.out.println(FourLetterOfLastName + TwoLetterOfFirstName + randomnum);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Exactly what part of this task are you having trouble with? Have you looked at the `java.util.Random` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class FirstNameLastName {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");
            String lastName = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
            String firstName = in.nextLine();
            
            String fourLetterOfLastName = lastName;
            
            
            if(lastName.length() > 4) {
                fourLetterOfLastName = lastName.substring(0, 4);
            }
           

            String twoLetterOfFirstName = firstName;
            
            if(firstName.length() > 2) {
                twoLetterOfFirstName = firstName.substring(0, 2);
            }
            

            String randomnum = String.valueOf(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10, 100));

            System.out.println(fourLetterOfLastName + twoLetterOfFirstName + randomnum);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into *[String.substring()](https://www.javatpoint.com/substring)* method.
Example:

```java
String fourLettersLastName = lastName.substring(0, 4); 
// if lastName = Jackson, then fourLettersLastName = Jack
```

For the random number you can look at *[Math.random()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-math-random-method)*.
Example:

```java
int randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
// In your case, max = 99 and min = 10
// The (int) cast is needed because Math.random() returns a double
```

In the end you concatenate everything (using the '+' sign) and print out for the user. A tip in the future when playing with Strings in Java is to use *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)*.

Other thing I noticed is the variable named *randomnum* which is against Java naming conventions (and almost every programming language). The way is supposed to be named is using camelCase (in this case, randomNum). You should check this [page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) for more info on this.